# Self Initiated Client Connecting Ansynchronous TCP Server in C#?

Tags: c#, tcp, network-programming, asyncsocket, tcpserver

I have a need to design a Asynchronous C# Server in which there are few needs.

1. There are numerous Clients that need to be handled
2. All the Clients are connected only when the connection requested/initiated by the Server
3. The Clients are non programmable devices, in which communication mechanism or connection handling, etc., cannot be modified

I am a noob for the world of C# and Network Programming.

All my searches for the "Asynchronous Network Server C#" ended up in landing the Servers that wait for the Clients to connect and transact.

Please help me in designing the Server.

Thanks a bunch in advance !! :)

Comment: Is the clients listening to some port?

Comment: Yes Izikon, all the clients need to listen to the same port of the Server